# Restricted conjugation map, proof should follow from the conjugation map?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$, and let $g\in G$. We define the map $F:G\to G$ to be the conjugation by $g$ map, $F(x)=gxg^{-1}$.

I have shown that $F$ is an isomorphism, and the second question is to show that $F|_H:H\to F(H)$ is an isomorphism.

I can't see why this isn't already proven by showing $F$ was an isomorphism.

It seems that $F|_H:H\to F(H)$ means that $F|_H$ is surjective by definition, and injectivity is absorbed from $F$.

Then showing it is a group homomorphism:

$F|_H(ab)=gabg^{-1}=gag^{-1}gbg^{-1}=F|_H(a)F|_H(b)$

And $F|_H(a+b)=g(a+b)g^{-1}=gag^{-1}+gbg^{-1}=F|_H(a)+F|_H(b)$

---

Am I missing something?

Comment: Nope, restricting an isomorphism to a subgroup results in an isomorphism between the subgroup and the image of the subgroup.

Comment: @levap That's what I mean though, they wanted me to prove secondly that $F|_H:H\to F(H)$ is an isomorphism, which follows immediately correct?

Comment: Correct, and this is true for general isomorphisms (you don't even need to use the specific form of $F$ that you are interested in your question).

Comment: Excellent, thanks @levap